# Heads off downstairs/down the stairs

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Context: Mike is at a party on the fifth floor of a building. There's an open view down to the fourth floor, and an open spiral staircase leading down there and not further. Mike gets into a fight with someone and decides to leave.

1. Mike flips them off and heads off downstairs.
2. Mike flips them off and heads off down the stairs.
3. Mike flips them off and heads off down the spiral staircase.

Could I use all these three sentences without problems? Which one would you use in the context?

Comment: The repetition of 'off' is a bit much. "... and goes/runs/saunters downstairs" would be enough.

Comment: All are equally valid, with (as usual in such questions!) a difference of emphasis: “downstairs” is a destination, “down the stairs/staircase” is a path.  If Mike goes out to the street, I'd say “down the stairs”, because “downstairs” implies he remains within the building.